# gRPC Exception: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: unavailable

Tags: java, grpc, micronaut, grpc-java

We are getting this error when we were running load test. After running 3 or 4 times the load test, we see this error: UNAVAILABLE: unavailable. Then, the next request after error, takes almost 30 seconds to complete.

This is the full stack trace:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: unavailable    
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:275) 
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:256)  
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:169)     at co.com.mycompany.myappname.grpc.client.ValidateTransactionGrpc$ValidateTransactionBlockingStub.validate(ValidateTransactionGrpc.java:157)    at co.com.mycompany.myappname.grpc.client.AppDetectorClient.invoke(AppDetectorClient.java:21)   
at co.com.mycompany.myappname.infrastructure.adapters.GrpcAdapter.provide(GrpcAdapter.java:33)  
at co.com.mycompany.myappname.application.services.AppDetectorService.execute(AppDetectorService.java:42)   
at co.com.mycompany.myappname.application.services.$AppDetectorService$Definition$Intercepted.$$access$$execute(Unknown Source)     
at ...
```

As you can see there is no a "Caused by" trace.

We are currently using java 11 with micronaut (v3.9.1)
grpc-protobuf version 1.49.0
grpc-netty-shaded version 1.49.0
grpc-stub version 1.49.0
grpc-services version 1.49.0

I saw some similiar errors reported here (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues?page=4&q=UNAVAILABLE) but nothing like this error.

See the logs from server but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

gRPC Java doesn't use the string "unavailable" (lower-case) for any library-generated error. So this is probably an error generated by the service you are load testing. You'd need to debug the server.